# что дописать в код чтобы музыка играла с бесконечным повторением

Tags: javascript

вот код что мне нужно добавить чтоб музыка играла циклом

```
var muz = 'http://vozmimp3.com/s1/down3/1-62v4-p8-89010356df3246/tikane_chasov__tik_tak.mp3';
var audio = new Audio(muz);
audio.play();
```

Comment: Обернуть `audio.play()` в `while(true) {}`?

Comment: Скорее всего нужно [свойство loop](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-media-loop)

Comment: большое спасибо все заработало!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нужно воспользоваться [свойством loop](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-media-loop)

```js
var muz = 'http://vozmimp3.com/s1/down3/1-62v4-p8-89010356df3246/tikane_chasov__tik_tak.mp3';
var audio = new Audio(muz);
audio.loop = true;
audio.play();
```

Comment: Твой комментарий был быстрее, считаем что ты первый =)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var audio = new Audio('http://vozmimp3.com/s1/down3/1-62v4-p8-89010356df3246/tikane_chasov__tik_tak.mp3'); 
audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
}, false);
audio.play();
```